# How do I read through a 2D array without searching out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array acting as a grid.

```
int grid[][] = new int[5][5];
```

How do I search through the grid sequentially as in (0,0),  (1,0),  (2,0),  (3,0),  (4,0) then (0,1), (1,1), (2,1) ... without getting any array out of bounds exceptions.

I'm new to programming and I just can't get my head around how to do this.

Comment: @Lino, damn I always forget that that site exists

Answer (score 2):

You know your lengths, now use a `for` loop to circle through the array.

```
for (int i = 0;i<5;i++){
    for (int j = 0;i<5;i++){
        int myInt = grid[i][j];
        //do something with my int
    }
}
```

To get the lengths at runtime you could do

```
int lengthX = grid.length; //length of first array
int lengthY = 0;
if ( lengthX>0){ //this avoids an IndexOutOFBoundsException if you don't know if the array is already initialized yet.
     lengthY = grid[0].length; //length of "nested" array
}
```

and then do the `for` loop with `lengthX` and `lengthY`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two nested loop in order to access the two dimensions of your array:

```
int grid[][] = new int[5][5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++  ) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++  ) {
        int value = grid[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 forloops like the following example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
         System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Also i would suggest that when initializing an array to write it like this:

```
 int[][] grid = new int[5][5]; // note the double brackets are after int and not grid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
  {
    System.out.println(grid[j][i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code (like the other answers) uses two for loops.
It does however add some handling of edge-cases

```
static int[] find(int[][] mtx, int valueToLookFor)
{
    int rows = mtx.length;
    if(rows == 0)
        return new int[]{-1,-1};
    int cols = mtx[0].length;
    if(cols == 0)
        return new int[]{-1, -1};
    for(int r=0;r<rows;r++)         
    {
        for(int c=0;c<cols;c++)
        {
            if(mtx[r][c] == valueToLookFor)
                return new int[]{r,c};
        }
    }
    return new int[]{-1,-1};
}
```